# chunkId does not match chunk

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-artifacts

I am trying to create a package into Azure Artifacts Feed.

```
az artifacts universal publish --organization https://dev.azure.com/abc --project Enterprise --scope project --subscription xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx --feed SecurityTesting --name security_testing --version 1.0.0 --description "Package for SecurityTestingFeed" --path .
```

Error occurred

> An error occurred on the service. chunkId does not match chunk. (Expected: 61B46E6AE59739B2845E4014CC63773C6117802BD87F71B63B0D6D2C4EBEFABA01, Actual: B5D99BE5323BB4338CE7C81D97AE54DD8310FDBC8EE3D522DF273CC0853AAF2001)
>
> Process ['/home/raj/.azure/azuredevops/cli/tools/artifacttool/ArtifactTool_linux-x64_0.2.219/artifacttool', 'universal', 'publish', '--service', 'https://dev.azure.com/abc', '--patvar', 'AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_ARTIFACTTOOL_PATVAR', '--feed', 'SecurityTesting', '--package-name', 'security_testing', '--package-version', '1.0.0', '--path', '.', '--project', 'Enterprise', '--description', 'Package for SecurityTestingFeed'] with PID 183 exited with return code 1

I searched a lot but not able to find any solution.

Comment: How about using the azure devops pipeline universal task instead of the command line for this issue? And are you publish the artifact with same file name?

Comment: I'm not sure about @raj, but I've ran into this issue numerous times as well.  I cannot use the azure devops pipeline universal task because we are executing the build and publishing process from an on-prem Jenkins server and not from an Azure DevOps Build.